# How to return a list in python?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm writing a program that takes a list of strings and return the length of of each string in a list.

```
def characters(nameLst):
    nameLst = ["Dan","jason","may","cole","Zhan"]
    outLst = []
    for i in range(len(nameLst)):
        outLst = outlst.append(len(nameLst))
    return (outLst) # should return [3, 5, 3, 4, 4]


nameLst = ["Dan","jason","may","cole","Zhan"]

def main():
    characters() 
main()
```

every time I run the program I get an error:

```
characters() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: You're writing in Python, a language with significant whitespace. Please make sure when you are pasting Python code that your indentation is correct. This time it was easy to figure out what you meant; next time, it might be complete and utter gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you defined the method `characters`, you said that it takes one argument, called `nameList`, but when you called it inside of the main method, you don't give it any arguments, if you use

```
characters(nameList)
```

in your main method, this should fix your error.

Also, your code will not give you the lengths of the different strings in `nameList`, rather it will give you a list full of the length of `nameList`. With the given list, you would get

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

because the expression that you append to the list is `len(nameList)`, when it should be `len(i)`.

Finally, `List.append()` will append to the list, so you don't need to use an `=` sign. If you replace the line with:

```
outlst.append(len(nameLst[i]))
```

This should give you the correct output.

Edit: I just realized that you redefine `nameLst` inside of the `characters` function. It is not necessary to have `nameLst` both inside and outside of the function. Either define `characters` with no arguments and define `nameLst` inside of `characters`, or add `nameLst` as an argument and don't define it inside of the function.

Comment: Its not len(i) as OP used i as an index. It should be len(nameList[i]) or better yet change the for loop to for i in nameList:.. then len(i) would work

Comment: You are correct, I changed the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

> every time I run the program I get an error: `characters() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

Here is how you invoke `characters()`:

```
characters()
```

Here is how it's defined:

```
def characters(nameLst):
```

Therefore, `python` expects you to call it like `characters(names)` instead of `characters()`.

The likely fix is to move the `nameLst` contents to `main`'s scope and pass it in (also your `characters` function does something different than you described.  fix below):

```
 def characters(nameLst):
     outLst = []
     for name in nameLst:
         outlst.append(len(name))

     return outLst # should return [3, 5, 3, 4, 4]


 def main():
     nameLst = ["Dan","jason","may","cole","Zhan"]

     characters(nameLst) 

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sidenote: Here is an easy implementation for your function:

```
def characters(nameLst):
    return map(len, nameLst)
```

Example:

```
>>> characters(["Dan","jason","may","cole","Zhan"])
[3, 5, 3, 4, 4]
```

I guess, directly replacing `characters(...)` with `map(len, ...)` would be the better solution... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've written characters(nameLst) with one parameter. Hence, when calling the function, be sure to pass the list in to the method.

Additionally, you will want to return(outLst) after your for loop - this way the entire list will be returned rather than just the first item.

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says. You declared the `characters` function to take a parameter called `nameLst`, but you called it with no parameters.  Either change

```
def characters(nameLst):
```

to

```
def characters():
```

effectively making `nameLst` a local variable, or pass a list as a parameter when you call the function.

```
def characters(nameLst):
    outLst = []
    for i in range(len(nameLst)):
        outLst = outlst.append(len(nameLst))
    return (outLst)

def main():
    nameLst = ["Dan", "jason", "may", "cole", "Zhan"]
    characters(nameLst)
```

Furthermore, your function would be better written as a list comprehension:

```
def characters(nameLst):
    return [len(name) for name in nameLst]
```

Note that you shouldn't expect any output from your program, since you never call `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the return, but the call. You've defined your function to take one parameter, but you haven't given it one when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You define a function `characters`, which takes a single argument `nameLst`, so you need to call it with an argument, like this:

```
def main():
    nameLst = ["Dan", "jason", "may", "cole", "Zhan"]
    result = characters(nameLst) # Save the returned list on the variable result
    print result # Print the result

main()
```